# How to inspect / visualize the current values of MS Azure Data Factory parameters and variables during the pipeline execution

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have ADF pipeline which execute SQL stored procedure (SP).

The SQL SP returns output parameters. I would like to visualize the content of the output parameters as soon as the "SP" Activity has finished.
In the next step I have "Set variable" Activity which assigns the values of the above mentioned output parameters to variables. I would like to visualize the content of the variables as well.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In the output tab, for every item of the grid, move the mouse over the name of the step, two or three icon buttons appear, the first open a popup to view step input, second for output and third for errors details